# Why am I getting an about:blank page instead of the correct url?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, ui-automation

Just wanna ask this problem of mine since I'm kinda stuck.
So I am currently creating a program that will get the url link of a page that will download a file by clicking a button.

Here's my code:

```
def get_url_reports(self):
    self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//xpath1']").click()
    try:
        element = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 30).until(
            EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//xpath2"))
        )
    finally:
        self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//xpath2").click()
        WebDriverWait(self.driver, 60).until(
            EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "xpath3')]")))
        self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "xpath3").click()
        sleep(3)
        self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "xpath4").click()
        WebDriverWait(self.driver, 60).until(
            EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "xpath5")))
        sleep(8)

    reports = ["report1_xpath", "report2_xpath","report3_xpath","report4_xpath"]

    for report in reports:
        sleep(2)
        self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH, report).click() #this will open and download the report
        self.driver.switch_to.window(self.driver.window_handles[i+1])
        sleep(5)
        current_url = self.driver.current_url
        print_url.append(current_url)
        self.driver.switch_to.window(self.driver.window_handles[0])
```

The problem:
I am getting the urls of the pdf files, but when it is an excel file, the url that i'm getting is "about:blank" but is continuing to download the correct file.
When I manually do this, there is a link that I am getting with these downloaded files.
I'm not sure as to why I am getting about:blank instead of the correct url

Sidenote: I also tried closing the new tabs being opened after getting the url, and having the same results as well. I'm using chromedriver as my browser by the way and using selenium 4.14

I'm new to python and selenium and i'm happy to learn new things so any input will be much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: you might try getting the "href" attribute of the "report" element you are clicking on.  You should also avoid using indexes for window/tab handles.  Instead get the current handle before the action that opens the new tab, then do that action, and get all the window handles, iterate through them and switch to the one that is not the current.  If you see an "about:blank" tab open, the URL never changes, and it doesn't close, this could be a bug.  What's the behavior when doing this manually?

Comment: there are a couple ways to download a file without opening a new tab.  One is to use an invisible iframe in the current tab.... the other is to use an ObjectURL where the file is saved in the browser's local storage.  (the URL would either be that of the iframe, or only used in an "ajax" call in a javascript.)

Comment: Thanks for the input about the indexes, already refactored them and not using it now for the window handles. When doing it manually, upon clicking the button, it will open a tab showing a link instead of about:blank and will download the file. 

However in the automation, about:blank is seen instead of the URL
I couldn't really get to try downloading it differently since downloading is not the issue. I just really need the links to download as I will use it to a different testcase

The element button btw doesn't have an @href attribute

Comment: not sure what would cause that.  If the site were detecting bot activity it doesn't seem like the download would work at all.  Maybe include the markup in your post.  (right-click, choose "inspect" and copy/paste the DOM into your post.)